# What is Java vmoptions file? Which libary/wrapper provides support for this file format to start java?

Tags: java

Traditional way to configure java is via custom `.bat` or `.sh` file with variable, like `JAVA_OPTS` that is placed in CLI for Java:

`java $JAVA_OPTS ...`

Some projects (SoapUI, AndroidStudio) use `.vmoptions` file. How can I add support for this file format to my Java app (both Windows / Linux)?

Comment: i know that install4j uses a .vmoptions file, http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/concepts/vmParameters.html

Comment: @jtahlborn I believe that there are some other tools here, as `install4j` requires `-J` prefix e.g. `-J-Xmx800m` and I see no any in SoapUI.vmoptions.

Comment: while there may be other tools (i don't know), i do know that install4j doesn't require a `-J` prefix on parameters.